# Additional type bounds in constructor

Tags: java, generics

Say I have a class like this:

```
class OrderedFoo<T> {

    public OrderedFoo(Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
        //Do something
    }

}
```

I could use this for non-comparable objects as the type parameter is not required to implement `Comparable`.

I could also use this for comparable objects, making use of [`Comparator#naturalOrder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder--).

Example:

```
OrderedFoo<Watchable> nonComparable = new OrderedFoo<>((a, b) -> foo());
OrderedFoo<String> comparable = new OrderedFoo<>(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

However, it gets somewhat tedious to have to specify a default comparator for comparable types. Is it possible to write a constructor with type parameters that will only accept a comparable type?

```
//Like this
public <???> OrderedFoo() {
    this(Comparator.naturalOrder());
}
```

I tried `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` but I get

```
(java.util.Comparator<? super T>)
in OrderedFoo cannot be applied to
(java.util.Comparator<T>)
```

Is this possible with a constructor?

Comment: But obviously `this(Comparator.<Something>naturalOrder());` isn't in the bounds of `<T>`: `Something` is an unbound type variable. You'd need `this(Comparator.<T>naturalOrder())` (if you need the type variable at all).

Comment: @AndyTurner I meant `Something` as a placeholder, not as a type. I agree I ideally shouldn't need the type specifier explicitly. I have removed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this directly with a constructor, because that constructor has to be applicable to all types; but you want it only to work for `Comparable` types.

Use a static factory method with a suitably-constrained type variable:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> OrderedFoo<T> naturalOrder() {
  return new OrderedFoo<>(Comparator.naturalOrdering());
}
```